# Ubuntu 12.04 high cpu usage

Tags: ubuntu, php

This server is ran more than 1,5 year without any problem, until yesterday. I see some wierd processes that i never seen before. But i don't know how i need to be start debugging the problem.

I attached a picture with a problem ( pids: 2611, 2621, 47316, 47329 ... etc.)

Picture: [image: process view]
[Large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cwqx.png)

Comment: What iowait percentage are you seeing? Post a screencap of top.

Comment: That's a standard php5-related cleanup cronjob that somehow got stuck. Can't you just reboot the server? If you want to debug, you can try strace, ltrace, lsof to see what the stuck processes are doing.

Comment: Can you put the output from the command `qshape deferred`? What is the main purpose of this server? (i.e. mail, web, database, etc...)

Comment: qshape deferred
                                         T  5 10 20 40 80 160 320 640 1280 1280+
                                  TOTAL  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     0
This is a LAMP server.